# Calling an object literal element inside of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call an object literal element inside of a function and it isn't working... when it gets down to calling the element "image" inside of the function it gives me an undefined error.

```
var w1 = {warframeName:"Ash", health:450, shield:300, power:150, armor:65.0, sprint:1.15, stamina:100, image:"images/warframes/ash.jpg"};

$(".woption").click(function() {
    var wClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];

    for(var x = 1; x <23; x++) {
        if(wClass == "w"+x) {
            $(".warframe_selector").css("background", "url(" + ('w'+x).image +") no-repeat", "important");
            $(".warframe_selector").css( "background-size", "100%" );
        } else {}
    }

    $("#cover").fadeOut(function() {});
    $(".warframe_option").fadeOut(function() {});
});
```

Comment: You know what we're going to ask, don't you?

Comment: No I don't :/ what are you asking?

Comment: define: "isn't working" (thats what were going to ask)

Comment: also, what are you expecting `('w'+x).image` to do?

Comment: I want the ('w' + x).image to get the image url in the var w1 array up above (there are a lot of places where I could have gone wrong)

Comment: `w1` isnt an array - its an object literal. Thats not me just being pedantic, its a completely different thing

Comment: My bad, I'm very new to javascript - does this means it can't work?

Comment: No, it means you just need to read up on the basicas of javascript. See my answer to get you going on this one

Comment: @Jamiec: While we are pendantic, `w1` is a *variable* containing an *object*. `{ }` is an object literal ;)

Comment: @FelixKling I bow to your Superior pedantry!

Comment: Wait, we can do better than that for pedantry, can't we?  "w1" is a String representing the _name_ of a variable... nevermind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `w1` isnt an array, its a  variable pointing to an object literal. Which means you just cant accesss it like `('w' + 1).image`. You have 2 options

1. Make it an array, access it like an array

   ```
   var w = [{warframeName:"Ash", health:450, shield:300, power:150, armor:65.0, sprint:1.15, stamina:100, image:"images/warframes/ash.jpg"}];
   ... w[x].image  ...
   ```
2. Make the object literal have some scope, and use square bracket notation to access it

   ```
    window.myNamespace = {};
    window.myNamespace.w1 = {warframeName:"Ash", health:450, shield:300, power:150, armor:65.0, sprint:1.15, stamina:100, image:"images/warframes/ash.jpg"}
   ... window.myNamespace['w' + x].image ...
   ```

Comment: In a numbered list, use 8 spaces (instead of 4) to create code blocks.  It's a weird markdown quirk.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Thanks, I only tried about 5 times to get that right with the proper numbered list before giving up!

Comment: The array method isn't working for me still... I will keep messing with it though...

Comment: @Nesiehr if the first method didnt work you either forgot to wrap your current declaration in square brackets (that was quite a subtle change) or the variable `w` is in a different scope.